# No 'ros' stack detected in candidates, ¿where is the stack?

Tags: ros, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

Sorry for disturbing you, i'm trying to install ROSGroovy in Slackware 14.0.

How can this be solved?

(Over-)Writing /home/user/ros/.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /home/user/ros
ERROR in rosinstall:
No 'ros' stack detected in candidates [].
Please add the location of a ros distribution to this command.

I have googled this error, and found that rosinstall is pointing to an empty url.

I also found that the ROS files coulbe in the /ros directory, but there are no files in the ros directory

My problem is, how can i fix that rosinstall is pointing to an empty url?
Or where are the files to install ROS?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76931/no-%27ros%27-stack-detected-in-candidates,-%C2%BFwhere-is-the-stack?/) by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, for some reason, i discovered that i can download diamondback in a laptop and i can download hydro and groovy in a desktop. Wonder why does this happen?

Anyway, i'll post another problem that i encountered, the problem is "rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros".

How can i fix it?

---

Originally posted by [Bernard_o](https://answers.ros.org/users/6446/bernard_o/) with karma: 26 on 2013-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1